# Trouble with exceptions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am learning about exceptions in  python and I am having trouble with some code. the following code is:

```
try:
    txt = open("C:\\Users\\Draco\\OneDrive\\Documents\\textfile.txt","r")
    try:
        txt.write("This is a test. Normal service will shortly resume!")
    finally:
        print("Content written to file successfully. Have a nice day.")
        txt.close()
except IOError:
    print("Error: unable to write the file. Check permissions")
```

Now when I execute the code I get the following to two lines:
Content written to file successfully. Have a nice day.
Error: unable to write the file. Check permissions

The issues I am having is that because the error, in this case being the "r" which should be "w" I should only get the message Error: unable to write the file. Check permissions. But I am getting both error and the success messages and I am unsure why

Comment: Why are you printing the success message in the `finally` block?

Comment: Check out this [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/open) You have to follow this format: `open("path_to_file", mode = 'r')

Comment: Your success message is in a `finally` block. The whole purpose of a `finally` block is that it is **always executed**.

Answer (score 1):

I'll break it down one by one for you.

1. Try block opened

   ```
   try:
   ```
2. File opened with read privileges.

   ```
   txt = open("C:\\Users\\Draco\\OneDrive\\Documents\\textfile.txt","r")
   ```
3. Try block opened, exception occurred when you wrote since you wrote to a readonly file object.

   ```
   try:
       txt.write("This is a test. Normal service will shortly resume!")
   ```
4. Since you have an inner try block, the nested finally is the first block executed.

   ```
   finally:
   ```
5. Printing success even though the file write failed.

   ```
   print("Content written to file successfully. Have a nice day.")
   ```
6. Closing the file, works fine

   ```
   txt.close()
   ```
7. Exception handler, now the exception is handled.

   ```
   except IOError:
       print("Error: unable to write the file. Check permissions")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`finally` [always executes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions):

> A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement,
>   whether an exception has occurred or not.

The process you are seeing:

1. Your script will not error on `txt = open(loc, 'r')` because at the stage it is not
   writing any data.
2. When it moves on to `txt.write` it errors and moves to `finally`,
   for the reason given above.
3. Since you have met an `IOError`, you will also see the message
   defined in your `except` clause.